# How to keep single responsibility when using self-type in Scala?

Tags: scala, self-type, cake-pattern

Using self-type for dependency injections, cause to expose public method of other traits ,which break the single responsibility principal. Let's me talk with example

```
trait Output {
  def output(str: String): Unit
}

trait ConsoleOutput extends Output {
  override def output(str: String): Unit = println(str)
}

class Sample {
  self: Output =>

  def doSomething() = {
    // I do something stupid here!
    output("Output goes here!")
  }
}

val obj = new Sample with ConsoleOutput
obj.output("Hey there")
```

My `Sample` class dependes on `Output` trait and of course I would like to use `Output` trait methods in my `Sample` class. But with above code example my `Sample` class expose `output` method which doesn't come from its functionality and break single responsibility of `Sample`.

How can I avoid it and keep using self-type and cake-pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Responsibility* of providing the output still lies with the component implementing `Output`. The fact that your class provides access to it is no different from something like:

```
  class Foo(val out: Output)
  new Foo(new ConsoleOutput{}).out.output
```

Sure, you can make `out` private here, but you could also have `.output` protected in `ConsoleOutput` if you don't want it accessible from outside as well.

(The answer to your comment in the other answer is that if you also want to use it "stand-alone", then you subclass it, and make `output` public in the subclass).

Comment: This is not correct. The *responsibility* for the methods on an object lie with the object itself even if the *implementation* comes from a superclasses of that object. I have given a more detailed explanation in my answer to this question.

Comment: @Tim no. Responsibility is with the implementation. The explanation you have given is wrong. Liskov substitution principle is not about responsibilities.

Comment: I've added some more text to my answer to explain why the single responsibility principle is about interfaces not implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The self type is not really relevant here. Inheriting from another class exposes the public methods of that class regardless of any self type. So any inheritance from a class with public methods can be said to break the single responsibility principle.

If the `trait` is intended to be use for dependency injection then it should make its methods `protected` so that they are not exposed.

```
trait Output {
  protected def output(str: String): Unit
}

trait ConsoleOutput extends Output {
  protected override def output(str: String): Unit = println(str)
}
```

---

#### Comment on the accepted answer

The accepted answer claims that the "Responsibility of providing the output still lies with the component implementing `Output`". This is incorrect, and shows confusion between a type and an implementation.

The behaviour of an object is specified by its type, not its implementation (Liskov substitution principle). The type is the contract that tells the user what the object can do. Therefore it is the *type* that specifies the responsibilities, not the *implementation*.

The type `Sample with ConsoleOutput` has the `output` method from the `Object` type and the `doSomething` method from the `Sample` type. Therefore it has the responsibility of providing an implementation of both of those methods. The fact that the implementation of `output` is in `ConsoleOuput` is irrelevant to the type and is therefore irrelevant to who is responsible for it.

The `Sample with ConsoleOutput` object could easily override the implementation of `output` in which case it would clearly be responsible for that method, not `ConsoleOutput`. The fact that `Sample with ConsoleOutput` chooses not to change the implementation of `output` does not mean that it is not responsible for it. The responsibilities of an object do not change when the implementation changes.

#### Explanation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

This principle is the first of the five [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles of software engineering. 
As Wikipedia explains, "The single responsibility principle [] states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class."

In other words, don't do this:

```
class MultipleResponsibilities {
   def computePi(places: Int): List[Int]
   def countVowels(text: String): Int
}
```

but do this instead:

```
class PiComputer {
  def computePi(places: Int): List[Int]
}

class VowelCounter {
   def countVowels(text: String): Int
}
```

`computePi` and `countVowels` are different parts of the functionality of the program and therefore they they should be encapsulated in different classes.

The third SOLID principle is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which says that the functionality of an object should depend solely on the type and should not be affected by the implementation. You should be able to change the implementation and still use the object in the same way with the same results.

Since the functionality of an object is fully defined by the type of an object, the responsibilities of an object are also fully defined by the type. Changing the implementation does not change the responsibilities.

Comment: As far as I know Protected is not solution for DI. For example I like to use `ConsoleOuput` independently for other usage. But self-type and trait are used in cake-pattern as DI. I'm looking to avoid it in cake-pattern.

Comment: If you are using `ConsoleOuput` for both DI and as a stand-alone class then you are using it for two different purposes and have already broken the single responsibility principle.